# Format string with updated integer values to display with textbox as columns

Tags: c#, string, winforms, textbox, string-formatting

if I have string with updated integer values with 8 digits maximum:

```
 string Str = ("A1: [ " + int1 + " ] A2: [ " + int2  + " ]" +  
           "\r\nA3: [ " + int3 + " ] A4: [ " + int4  + " ]" +  
           "\r\nB1: [ " + int5 + " ] B2: [ " + int6  + " ]" + 
           "\r\nB3: [ " + int7 + " ] B4: [ " + int2  + " ]\r\n");
```

which is:

```
  A1: [ 126.453 ] A2: [ 8.940 ]
  A3: [ 11.3 ] A4: [ 122.4 ]    
  B1: [ 6566.2 ] B2: [ 3444.76 ]    
  B3: [ 6.562 ] B4: [ 34.76 ]
```

How can I format it for iterations display with textbox output side by side as columns with corresponding spacing between part with count integer size:

```
  A1: [ 126.453 ] A2: [ 348656.2 ]    B1: [ 35.7 ] B2: [ 65.1 ] 
  A3: [ 8.90 ] A4: [ 34.76 ]          B3: [ 3.97770 ] B4: [ 87700.67 ]
```

I found several ways, but not really sure how to use it for this case, how to figure out with updated numbers and assign my string to integer length this way:

```
    int pd = 3;
    int mx1 = "Hello World!".Length;
    int mx2 = "1234.56732".Length;
    int mx3 = "Name".Length;

    string f0 = "{0,-" + (mx1 + pd) + "}";
    string f1 = "{1,-" + (mx2 + pd) + "}";
    string f2 = "{2,-" + (mx3 + pd) + "}";

    string f = f0 + f1 + f2;

    Console.WriteLine(f, "Hello World!", 1234.56732, "Month");
    Console.WriteLine(f, "How are you?", 78.44, "Day");
    Console.WriteLine(f, "Hi", 2311.654, "Year");
```

It would be good to hear some useful advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `String.PadRight()` method to align values:

```
var nums = new List<double>() {
    126.453, 8.94, 11.3, 122.4, 6566.2, 3444.76, 6.562, 34.76
};

var maxLen = nums.Select(n => n.ToString().Length).Max();
var strVals = nums.Select(n => n.ToString().PadRight(maxLen)).ToList();

textBox1.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 10);
var pos = 0;
foreach (var strVal in strVals)
    //Debug.Write($"NUM{++pos}: [ {strVal} ]    {(pos % 2 == 0 ? "\r\n" : "")}");
    textBox1.Text += $"NUM{++pos}: [ {strVal} ]    {(pos % 2 == 0 ? "\r\n" : "")}";
```

**Output:**

```
NUM1: [ 126,453 ]    NUM2: [ 8,94    ]    
NUM3: [ 11,3    ]    NUM4: [ 122,4   ]    
NUM5: [ 6566,2  ]    NUM6: [ 3444,76 ]    
NUM7: [ 6,562   ]    NUM8: [ 34,76   ]
```

Comment: Hello, my output with your code is one column with empty lines between pairs, one under the other:

'NUM1: [ 126.453 ]
NUM2: [ 8.94    ]

NUM3: [ 11.3    ]
NUM4: [ 122.4   ]

NUM5: [ 6566.2  ]
NUM6: [ 3444.76 ]

NUM7: [ 6.562   ]
NUM8: [ 34.76   ]'

Comment: Looks like you made a wrong copy-paste. I have checked again - it works. Here is a [screenshot](https://k76i.imgup.net/VSScreenShf109.png)

Comment: Debug.Write displays this result with VS output, not sure how to display this with textbox, I tried to add it to the list, but seems like it is a wrong way, not sure

Comment: To use it with text box, you should use some monospace font.
Look on updated example.